# how to generate a random matrix less than or equal to another matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Want to generate a random 0-1 matrix less than or equal to another matrix in python.
for example, I have a specific matrix:

```
a=[1 0 0
   0 1 1
   0 0 1]
```

And I want to generate a random matrix:

```
y=[1 0 0
   0 0 0 
   0 0 1]
```

As we can see, a>=y. How can I generate random matrix y in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say to generate a random matrix, then set down to 0 where the values are too high

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]])
print(a)

y = np.random.randint(2, size=a.shape)
y[y > a] = 0
print(y)
```